# Replace spaces and commas from URL

Tags: javascript

I am using Algolia places search, I want to pass it to the URL from a form input value.

What is the best way to replace the "%20" in:

```
mywebsite.com/location_name=Fort%20Lauderdale,%20Florida,%20United%20States%20of%20America
```

and "," with "-" or remove completely?

#### Input

```
mywebsite.com/?location_name=Fort%20Lauderdale,%20Florida,%20United%20States%20of%20America
```

#### Desired output

I would like it like this:

```
mywebsite.com/?location_name=Fort-Lauderdale-Florida-United-States-of-America
```

Or maybe just:

```
mywebsite.com/?location_name=Fort-Lauderdale
```

Comment: ask this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697841/how-change-space-to-be-line-in-url

Comment: Wouldn't recommend doing this, but here ya go: `decodeURI(url).replace(/,/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,'-')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a simple regex like so:

```js
 

const str = "mywebsite.com/?location_name=Fort%20Lauderdale,%20Florida,%20United%20States%20of%20America";
const modified = str.replace(/\,~|\%20/g, "-");
console.log(modified);
```

The above regex matches a comma or a URL-encoded space.

Answer (score 0):

in php

```
$link = "http://mywebsite.com/?location_name=Fort%20Lauderdale,%20Florida,%20United%20States%20of%20America";
echo str_replace(array(',', '%20'), array('','-'), $link);
```